# How to remove $ mark and add € mark to number format in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

The belove code give me $00.00 format number and and i want €00,00 like this.
WHat i really want is , when User type on EditeText it should like bigin €00,09 like this .
And another problem is if i enter numbers and delete fastly the app crash.
Any one know how to solve this?

```
public class MoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText mEditText) {
        editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(mEditText);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       EditText editTex = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if(!s.toString().equals(editTex.getText())) {
            editTex.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[€,.]", "");
            double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed / 100));
            editTex.setText(formatted);
            editTex.setSelection(formatted.length());

            editTex.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question to be more readable. Also, please ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the main question is how to format your double with a Euro sign. For this, you can simply set the currency `NumberFormat` should use:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
format.setCurrency(currency);

System.out.println(format.format(40.27));
```

Output:

```
€40.27
```

This method only adds the € sign, but does not change the decimal point or anything else. Alternatively, you can also use the format of a specific country. For example France:

```
NumberFormat france = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
System.out.println(france.format(40.27));
```

Output:

```
40,27 €
```